# Is writing to uninitialized memory allocated by allocator UB? And what about reading it afterwards?

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior

```cpp
struct Foo{ 
    int i;
    int j;
};

int main(){ 
    std::allocator<Foo> bar;
    Foo* foo = bar.allocate(1);
    foo->i = 0;
    return foo->i; // ignore the memory leak, it's irrelevant to the question
}
```

I'm curious about whether there are undefined behaviors in the snippet above? Will the conclusion vary according to the type of `Foo` (e.g. not all members are POD type, or `Foo` has virtual functions)?

Comment: Which version of C++ specifically can you use?  These rules had a major change starting in C++20

Comment: @NathanOliver I am not asking for a specific use, so I'd appreciate it if you can explain both cases (prior and post C++20).

Comment: Please note that the `construct()` and `destroy()` member functions of `std::allocator<T>` have been deprecated in C++17 and already removed in C++20.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an error to use raw memory in which an object has not been constructed.
We must construct objects in order to use memory returned by
`allocate`. Using **unconstructed memory** in other ways is undefined. [Source: C++ Primer, Fifth Edition](https://www.amazon.in/C-Primer-Stanley-B-Lippman/dp/0321714113)

Since you have not used `construct` the behavior of your program is undefined **prior to C++20**.

> **Undefined behavior** means anything<sup>1</sup> can happen *including but not limited to* the program giving your expected output. But **never rely**(or make conclusions based) on the output of a program that has undefined behavior.

So the output that you're seeing(maybe seeing) is a result of undefined behavior. And as i said **don't rely on the output** of a program that has UB.

So the first step to make the program correct would be to remove UB. **Then and only then** you can start reasoning about the output of the program.

---

<sup><sup>1</sup>For a more technically accurate definition of undefined behavior see [this](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/ub) where it is mentioned that: **there are no restrictions on the behavior of the program**.</sup>

Comment: C++ Primer is not an authoritative reference. It is also fairly old and does not reflect the current standard. The program is well-defined starting from C++20 (and the intent to make it well-defined was there from the very beginning, just not codified).

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. I have added that this is undefined behavior prior to C++20 in my edited answer.

Comment: Hmm it looks like P0593R6 was retroactively applied to the previous standards as well, so the behaviour is now defined according to any standard edition (but don't quote me on that).

Comment: If the behavior was truly undefined (and not just a bug in the standard), every single C-style `malloc` would have been undefined when compiled as C++. Therefore, it definitely was a bug in the standard.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Ok so technically does  this mean that C++ Primer has a mistake/bug or C++ Primer is still technically correct about the quoted statement? If it is indeed a bug/mistake in the book C++ Primer then can we safely use unconstructed memory prior to C++20?

Comment: @SebastianRedl That's exactly the nature of the defect that the paper fixes. The intent of the standard was not to make C-style malloc usage undefined, but the wording did make it undefined.

Comment: The correction was applied after the Primer was released, so there was no bug at that time. Now this piece of information seems to be obsolete. All implementations did it correctly anyway so it always was safe in practice. Now it is also sanctioned by the standard.  One of the job of the standard is to codify existing practice, and this does sometimes happen with a delay. It is totally normal.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem.: Did an implementation just coincientally happen to work correctly, or had the behavior always been so obviously defined in the pre-existing language the C++ Standard was written to describe that the authors of the Standard had omitted to actually specify it because there had never been any question about its meaning?

Comment: It is pretty obvious how C-style malloc should work, and it always worked this way in all C++ implementations, because why shouldn't it?

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. According to your helpful comments here, is the assignment to uninitialized memory 100% safe now? For example, if`auto p = alloc.allocate(1); *p = some_value;` is correct and safe code now, is the assignment to *p using the data type's copy-assignment/move-assignment operator?

Comment: @Peng I is not safe if there are non-trivial constructors (and assignment operators without constructors are useless).